# How do I create a Linux App without Snap?

Tags: linux, flutter

Flutter's main Linux platform seems to be via [Canonical's snap format](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-linux-alpha-with-canonical-19eb824590a9) with is not supported by all Linux distribution.

How do I create a Linux app in Flutter when I don't have access to snap?

Comment: That’s a fairly broad question. Hundreds, possibly thousands of Linux distros. Rpm, Deb, binary, are some of the common ways to distribute Linux software. What distribution are you targeting. Also, snaps are designed to run across most, maybe all distros. So... why target something other than snap?  Specifics about what distro you want to target would help.

Comment: @NicholasRees : The point is to not only target a single distro.

Comment: Snap is the only packaging format I’ve heard of that targets all distros.

Comment: Hello @all, is there any update on this? I have been researching into the same, could not find anything apart snap format for linux app :(
Let me re-phrase question, is it possible to generate linux .rpm packages from flutter app?